# With or without a comma RESTRICTIVE or NON-RESTRICTIVE?

Tags: grammar

What's the difference between the sentences below?

They only hired **unmarried women who were selected because of their beauty.**

They only hired **unmarried women, who were selected because of their beauty.**

Comment: (1) is restrictive, no comma; (2) is non-restrictive, yes comma.

Answer (score 1):

### There is no functional difference in the sentences

They only hired unmarried women and they made their selections of those women based on attractiveness.

The second has better punctuation as it more closely represents the way the sentence would be spoken - there would be a natural pause between the first clause and the second.

Answer (score -2):

**They only hired unmarried women who were selected because of their beauty.**
= The only hired unmarried women that were beautiful. Not every kind of unmarried woman but the ones with beauty.

**They only hired unmarried women, who were selected because of their beauty.**
=They only hired unmarried women, and these women were selected because of their beauty.

Comment: Is my explanation correct?

Comment: Yes. In your first sentence, not all unmarried are beautiful. In your second sentence, all unmarried women are beautiful.

Comment: Does the sentence really mean that all unmarried are beautiful? I think a similar sentence like "I only sell sports cars, which my cousin sells to me" only means two things: I sell sports cars, and I buy them from my cousin. I am not saying that my cousin sells all sports cars in the world.